# Chrome console remove filtering

Tags: google-chrome, console

Chrome console shows message "x items hidden by filters" on the top of the console. How do I show the hidden items?

- When I do right click -> Filter -> "Unhide all" is disabled
- Previously that message used to be *in* the console, not on the top of the console and I could click that message and do unhide. Now the message is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZML6B.png) beside the Filter input at the top of the console. Expanding this dropdown will provide options for Default, Verbose, Info, Warnings, Errors. The dropdown will change to [All Levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do0jA.png) if you select all the options (Verbose, Info, Warnings, and Errors). With the dropdown set to All Levels, no console entries should be hidden.